# MySQL and Product Cross Sell (XSell)

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

Tables that I am working with:

```
       products table
|------------|-------------|
| product_id | product_sku |
|------------|-------------|
|     2345   |   G54321    |
|------------|-------------|
|     2346   |   G64321    |
|------------|-------------|

     products_xsell
|----|------------|-------------|
| ID | product_id | xsell_id    |
|----|------------|-------------|
|  3 |    2345    |   2346      |
|----|------------|-------------|
|  4 |    2346    |   2345      |
|----|------------|-------------|
```

I receive a csv in the following format:

```
SKU, Related_Items
2345,"2346,2347,2349"
112,"4840,4841,4844,4890,4891"
```

I am able to successfully query for SKU's based on the data in the XSELL table with the following:

```
Select
  products.products_model As 'Displayed Product',
  products1.products_model As 'Related Item'
From
  products_xsell Inner Join
  products On products_xsell.products_id = products.products_id Inner Join
  products products1 On products_xsell.xsell_id = products1.products_id
```

and it returns:

```
|-------------------|----------------|
| Displayed Product | Related Item   |
|-------------------|----------------|
|     G54321        |   G64321       |
|-------------------|----------------|
|     G64321        |   G54321       |
|-------------------|----------------|
```

I am looking to be able to read in the csv file.
Essentially create a 'cross join' of sorts to build all 'reverse' cross sells, then look up associated product id's from the given sku's and insert them into the products_xsell table.

For instance, if the file has a row of sku's:

```
2345,"2346,2347,2349"
```

I would like to build out the following:

```
2345,2346
2345,2347
2345,2349
2346,2345
2346,2347
2346,2349
2347,2345
2347,2346
2347,2349
2349,2345
2349,2346
2349,2347
```

Get the associated product id's from the above skus:

```
54321,64321
54321,49245
54321,99499
64321,54321
64321,49245
64321,99499
49245,54321
49245,64321
49245,99499
99499,54321
99499,49245
99499,64321
```

And insert them into products_xsell table to build the cross sell and reverse cross sell relationships:

```
     products_xsell
|------------|-------------|
| product_id | xsell_id    |
|------------|-------------|
|     54321  |   64321     |
|------------|-------------|
|     54321  |   49245     |
|------------|-------------|
|     54321  |   99499     |
|------------|-------------|
|     64321  |   54321     |
|------------|-------------|
|     64321  |   49245     |
|------------|-------------|
|     64321  |   99499     |
|------------|-------------|
|     49245  |   54321     |
|------------|-------------|
|     49245  |   64321     |
|------------|-------------|
|     49245  |   99499     |
|------------|-------------|
|     99499  |   54321     |
|------------|-------------|
|     99499  |   64321     |
|------------|-------------|
|     99499  |   49245     |
|------------|-------------|
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you have a clear idea of what you want to do.  What have you done towards implementing this? Where are you running into problems?

Comment: I think this can be easily done with a helper Numbers table. Read here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable

Comment: @MikeBrant  I am able to read in the csv just fine and assign them variables, but I am stuck at the building out the sku arrays in SQL.   Especially if one has 3 related products and another has 8.   The if null logic and the array building is where I am having a tough time wrapping my head around right now.

Comment: @cha  I will have to read and reread those articles on numbers tables, to see if I can wrap my non-DBA head around the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Numbers table and the csv table is called csv, the query SELECT created easily like this:

```
select c.sku, n.n from csv c INNER JOIN Numbers n ON 
INSTR(CONCAT(',', c.Related_Items, ','), CONCAT(',', CAST(n.n AS CHAR), ',')) > 0
UNION ALL
select n.n, c.sku from csv c INNER JOIN Numbers n ON 
INSTR(CONCAT(',', c.Related_Items, ','), CONCAT(',', CAST(n.n AS CHAR), ',')) > 0
```

But you need the helper Numbers table that is populated with values from 1 to the maximum SKU possible in your system.

Check this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4980/10) for an example with the Numbers populated with the values from from 2345 to 2349